# argue invertibalitiy of $A = B^4 + 3 B^2 + 7 B + 3 I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $B  $  be a $3\times 3$ matrix.

argue invertibalitiy o $A = B^4 + 3 B^2 + 7 B + 3 I$

I guess getting it to product form and trying on determinant will work by dont konw how to I wish someone would know.

by the way Im intereset if there is any other way

Comment: $B=-I\implies A = I+3I-7I+3I=0$

Comment: Why would you expect this to be invertible, without additional conditions on $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix can be written as $A = p(B)$ where $p$ is the polynomial
$$
p(x) = x^4 + 3x^2 + 7x + 1
$$
By the spectral mapping theorem, the matrix $A$ will be invertible if and only if none of the eigenvalues of $B$ is a solution to $p(x) = 0$.  That is, $A$ will be invertible if and only if none of [these values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%20%2B%203x%5E2%20%2B%207x%20%2B%203%20%3D%200) is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Moreover, if we know all $3$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $B$, we may compute this new determinant as
$$
\det(A) = p(\lambda_1)p(\lambda_2)p(\lambda_3)
$$